# Cannot rename item at "c:\hi.txt" because item does not exist

Tags: powershell

Trying to teach myself PowerShell for work, and I thought I'd start by renaming an empty txt file. The file is 100% inside my C drive, and I've made sure the syntax is correct. What may my issue be?

```
rename-item -path c:\hi.txt -newname hello.txt
Rename-Item : The item does not exist
```

Edit: It turns out the file name was hi.txt with an extra extension hidden, so it's really hi.txt.txt. Now I'm getting a permissions error even though I am an administrator and created the text file.

```
rename-item -path c:\hi.txt.txt -newname hello.txt
Rename-Item : Access to the path is denied
```

Comment: Show some code?

Comment: Hard to help with code we can't see.  Don't describe it to us.  **Show** us.

Comment: "*What may my issue be?*" - If it was a permissions issue, like UAC as I expected for changes to C:\ then it would say AccessDenied. Hmm, If you see by one method that the file exists, then that view must be deceptive. Explorer is deceptive by default, so you have "hide file extensions" on and I guess the file is actually named `hi.txt.txt` ? Alternately have you named it with a space either as the first or last character, something which is visually not there?

Comment: I have added the code in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. My account did not have local admin perms. I have domain administrative privileges. After signing in as the local admin account, I tried and it worked.

Comment: By default joining a computer to a domain puts the domain admins group in the local administrators group, thus a domain admin not having local admin privileges is a little ... odd.

Comment: What difference does that make? Ordinary users can still see files in `c:\>` even if they can't change them - and if they try they get 'AccessDenied' instead of 'does not exist' - at least, I do when I try...